# No covers after copying shared iTunes songs

Tags: itunes

I got a new MacBook and now I would like to transfer all my media files via iTunes sharing from my old MacBook to the new one. But sometimes the **covers** are not copied.

Does someone know why and **how I can** copy my songs **with covers**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience:  there are 2 ways that itunes associates art work with songs:

- one is in the "Album Artwork" folder in itunes.  this can be updated from inside itunes in the menus.  these images stay in a folder and get some soft association with the music files.
- the other method is added manually with the gui, cutting and pasting.  these get added into the mp3 file.

it seems to me that i've tried to xfer the album artwork folder different ways before, but it doesn't work unless you copy the whole itunes setup.

Comment: That is right. If the cover image can be a part of the song file itself or managed by iTunes. In the later case the cover images are stored in a separate folder. I found an article in a German magazine with an AppleScript for storing the cover in the file itself. But I have not tried the script. You can find it at ftp://ftp.heise.de/pub/ct/listings/0905-172.zip